# Beginner runner/jogger heart rate question

Tags: cardiology

I am an it guy 220 lbs 6ft1 35 years old. With chest strap measurement my maximum heart rate is around 192 bpm. (Did warmup and 3 minutes thread mill intervals to measure)

For a long period of time, my spare time for gym was very poor. I did 15 mins @ 5.4mph with 5 minutes cooldown twice a week. No other exercise. At work I mostly sit. My background has a family heart disease and I fell on my chest more than 1 year ago (hospital test had everything normal).

I did physical last week: Resting heart rate 65 to 80. Blood pressure normal. EKG tested normal.

Every since I brought the heart monitor I encountered huge problem with heart rate. When normally walking at 3.8 mph for 5 mins bpm is 115.

When jogging at 4.3 mph for 5-7 mins bpm reaches a whopping 152 bpm.

I need some advice as good advice is not cheap in my area (cardiologist).

Could this be a blood cloth problem? Or because having too much fat in the chest area? (pressing on blood vessels) I am trying to gauge how urgent to see the doc again. Or this is something like normal for runners? I am by no means worried, its just in today's busy world I can barely book 1 open meeting next week and I also have a fully booked week after. I have to balance my work week time between family, money and health.

So just wondering if this wierd spike is normal for somebody with my background. Also worth knowing, what more tests should I do if I decide on being very prudent and seeing primary doc again.

ps: I tried breathing more through the nose, sometimes that affects bpm. When doing 20mins @ 5.4 mph or more, I need 10 mins cooldown otherwise i get left year tinnitus/pressure for ~15mins. I do not know if ps sections details are relevant.

psps: not using caffeine or alcohol, 2-5 mins warmup.